# Mathematica won't maximize my function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to maximize two functions. For the first one, the code runs correctly and returns the desired answer:

```
Maximize[{
    ax (Log[a] - Log[ax + cy]) + 
    bx (Log[b] - Log[bx + dy]) + 
    cy (Log[c] - Log[ax + cy]) + 
    dy (Log[d] - Log[bx + dy]),
    x >= 0, y >= 0, x + y == 1
  }, 
  {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {ax Log[a] + bx Log[b] + cy Log[c] - ax Log[ax + cy] - cy Log[ax + cy] + 
>       dy Log[d] - bx Log[bx + dy] - dy Log[bx + dy], 
>  {x -> 1/2, y -> 1/2}}
> ```

But for the second one,

```
Maximize[{
    (1/2) (x Log[x] + y Log[y] + u Log[u] + v Log[v]) - 
    (1/2) (x + u) Log[(1/2) (x + u)] - 
    (1/2) (y + v) Log[(1/2) (y + v)], 
    x >= 0, y >= 0, u >= 0, v >= 0, 
    x + y == 1, u + v == 1
  }, 
  {x, y, u, v}]
```

I just get the same thing I wrote as an input.

What am I doing wrong? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the answer with `NMaximize` command?

```
NMaximize[{(1/2) (x Log[x] + y Log[y] + u Log[u] + v Log[v]) 
            - (1/2) (x + u) Log[(1/2) (x + u)] - (1/2) (y + v) Log[(1/2) (y + v)], 
           x >= 0, y >= 0, u >= 0, v >= 0, x + y == 1, u + v == 1}, {x, y, u, v}]
```

> ```
> NMaximize::nnum: "The function value Indeterminate is not a number at 
>  {u,v,x,y} = {2.89263*10^-8,1.,1.,0.} >>
>
> {0.693147, {u -> 5.00551*10^-9, v -> 1., x -> 1., y -> 3.92799*10^-8}}
> ```